# Numpy and matplotlib: Can't edit an image array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

pic = Image.open('mountain1.jpg')
pic_array = np.asarray(pic)
# plt.imshow(pic_array[:,:,2], cmap='gray')
pic_array[:,:,2]=0
plt.imgshow(pic_array)
plt.show()
```

i get the following error/ pic_array[:,:,2]=0
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only How do i edit the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the code the original image and the numpy array share the same memory. hence the read-only error when you try to update the array.

Create the copy as the original array and it should be fine.

Another small thing that I noticed is plt.imgshow(image) is used instead of plt.imshow(image).

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

pic = Image.open('mountain1.jpg')
# copy of the numpy array so that the original image is not changed.
pic_array = np.asarray(pic).copy()
pic_array[:,:,2]=0
plt.imshow(pic_array)
```

Cheers!